# Finding the maximum value in a stack by using another stack?

Tags: c++, stack, max

I have the following code for finding the max value in a stack. It's working but should I use another approach for finding the max value because after calling the getMax() function, I'm not able to display the stack a.

```
int Sorter:: getMax(){
    c.push(a.top());
    a.pop();
    while(!a.empty()){
            if(a.top() > c.top()){
            c.pop();
                    c.push(a.top());
                    a.pop();
            }
            else
                    a.pop();
    }
    return c.top();
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use any variables other than the two stacks? Is the original stack supposed to remain in it's original state by the end of the algorithm, or can it be modified?

Comment: Oh yes @MartinEpsz you're right cause I realize that after finding the maximum I could not display the values in the a. How can I keep it as original?

Comment: Why are you using an entire stack (`c`) only to keep a single value in it at all time!? Use a regular variable.

Comment: Oh yes this seems reasonable, i'll keep a regular variable rather than a stack for c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the maximum value in a side variable:

```
int max = a.top();
while(!a.empty()){
  c.push(a.top());
  a.pop()
  if(c.top() > max){
    max = c.top(); // find the maximum among the values of a.
  }
}

// This loop can be replaced with a.swap(c). As jogojapan mentioned.
// It is to demonstrate the principal.
while(!c.empty())
{
  a.push(c.top());  // return the values back into a
  c.pop();
}

return max;
```

Comment: Since this is for C++, you could use `a.swap(c);` instead of the second loop.

Comment: @jogojapan, your'e right of course. I didn't remember that.

Answer (score 3):

The `O(1)` time and memory method of finding the maximum value of stack is the following:

1. For each element in stack, let's store maximum value **below** this element.
2. When pushing an element, its stored (maximum) value will be `max(st.top().value, st.top().maxValue)`
3. When popping an element, don't need to change anything.

So you can obtain the maximum of all elements inside the stack in `O(1)` time and memory complexity.

Pseudocode:

```
class StackWithMax
{
struct node
{
    int value; // an actual value;
    int maxValue; // maximum of below elements
};

stack<node> st;

public:
void pop()
{
    st.pop();
}

void push(const int &val)
{
   node newNode;
   newNode.value = val;
   newNode.maxValue = (st.empty() == true ? -INFINITY : max(st.top().maxValue, st.top().value) );
   st.push(newNode);
}

int maxStackValue() const
{
    assert(st.empty() == false);
    return st.top().maxValue;
}

};
```

Comment: If you store a "local" maximum in _each_ element, time complexity for finding the maximum at any time is indeed O(1), but the added _memory_ complexity is actually O(n).

Comment: You are right. Just meant this as O(1) for every element.

Comment: On that basis, all standard library containers of C++ have memory complexity O(1). That's not a very useful way of looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a working code, here's what you need to analyze.

1. What is the time complexity and space complexity of your existing solution?
2. As you might already know, there's a trade-off between time and space, can you use up **more space** to achieve better time complexity?

Comment: Hint: Use an Auxiliary Stack to keep track of maximum value that you encounter while inserting into the original stack.

Comment: Oh thanks @srinivas I'll keep in mind what you've already wrote. I've edited my question now, I understand the error because.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is look through the whole stack and save the answer, and then use the secodn stack to rebuild the original.

```
int Sorter:: getMax(){
    if(a.empty)
    {
        //handle this however you see fit
    }

    int res = a.top;
    //search for the maximum
    while(!a.empty()){
        if(a.top() > res){
            res = a.top();
        }
        c.push(a.top());
        a.pop();
    }

    //restore the original stack
    while(!c.empty()){
        a.push(c.top());
        c.pop();
    }
    return res;
}
```

As an aside, "a" and "c" are bad variable names. I kept them to be consistent with your code. You probably should use something more descriptive.

Comment: Oh so you mixed the comments, I'm changing the c as a regular variable as "res", and I'm storing each element of stack a in the c.

Comment: Since this is for C++, you can use `a.swap(c);` instead of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think if temp variable is allowed then it becomes quite easier.
Algorithm:

Put top element of stack A to temp variable temp=StackA.top();
2. Pop an element from Stack A and check if it is greater than value of temp variable. 
    2.1 If yes, copy the value to temp and push the same to Stack B.
    2.2 Else just push value to Stack B.
3. Repeat step 2 until Stack A is empty

I know this looks like an obvious (and nothing special)solution. But it preserves the elements of stack, offcourse if you want them in same order then you can add one more step to copy all pop all elements from stack B and push it back to stack A.